# How to compare lists in python in subgroups

Tags: python, list

I'm new in python so any help or recomendation is appreciated.

What I'm trying to do is, having two lists (not necessarily inverted).

For instance:

```
l1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
l2 = [5,4,3,2,1]
```

Comparing them to return the common values, but not as anyone would normally do, which in this case, the return will be all the elements of the list, because they are the same, just inverted.
What I'm trying to compare is, the same thing but like in stages, or semi portions of the list, and check if there is any coincidence until there, if it is, return that element, if not, keep looking in the next group.

For instance:
the first iteration, would check (having the lists previously defined:

```
l1 = [1]
l2 = [5]
#is there any coincidence until there? -> false (keep looking)
```

2nd iteration:

```
l1 = [1, 2]
l2 = [5, 4]
#is there any coincidence until there? -> false (keep looking)
```

3rd iteration:

```
l1 = [1, 2, 3]
l2 = [5, 4, 3]
#is there any coincidence until there? -> true (returns 3, 
#which is the element where the coincidence was found, not necessarily 
#the same index in both lists)
```

Having in mind that it will compare the last element from the first list with all from the second till that point, which in this case will be just the first from the second list, if no matches, keep trying with the element immediately preceding the last from the first list with all from the second, and so on, returning the first item that matches.

Another example to clarify:

```
l1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
l2 = [3,4,5,6,7]
```

And the output will be 3

A tricky one:

```
l1 = [1,2,3,4]
l2 = [2,1,4,5]
```

1st iteration

```
l1 = [1]
l2 = [2]
# No output
```

2nd iteration

```
l1 = [1,2]
l2 = [2,1]
# Output will be 2
```

Since that element was found in the second list too, and the item that I'm checking first is the last of the first list [1,**2**], and looking if it is also in the sencond list till that point [**2**,1].

All of this for needing to implementate the bidirectional search, but I'm finding myself currently stuck in this step as I'm not so used to the for loops and list handling yet.

Comment: [What have you tried so far?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592)

Comment: @Nacho What do you mean by a "coincidence"? Is it important that 3 appeared in the last spot for both lists, or does it only matter that both lists contained a 3? For example, what should the output be for lists [1,2,3,4,5] and [5,3,4,2,1]?

Comment: If the output is still 3 in that case, then what is the output in a case like [1,2,3,4] and [2,1,4,3]? Should the output be 1,2, or both?

Comment: The requirements aren't really clear to me. Do you want to return whether any indices have matching values between two lists?

Comment: @MattDMo I've tried to change the representation of the lists to queues, but still not find a way to compare it as it requires to, I've been checking on the list documentation but after 3 days of been stuck on the same point started feeling frustrated, I decided looking for help, or any recommenation.

Comment: @BenGrossmann It is just important that 3 appeared in both lists till that moment, having the same index in both lists is not necessary, in that specific case, it first compare [1] and [2] no output, then [1,2] and [2,1], then the output will be 2, since 2 is also in the 2nd list, not because of the index where it was found, but because the number 2 was the element found in both lists, it compares from the last to the first element from the first list, if any index of the second list contains that element too.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Not specifically the index, but which value was found in both lists, having in mind that it will compare the last element from the first list with all from the second, if no matches, keep trying with the element immediately preceding the last from the first list with all from the second, and so on, returning the first item that matches, please let me know if any more examples are needed in the post.

Comment: @Nacho So why should the inputs [1,2,3],[2,1,3] result in the output 2 instead of 1? Or, to make the example a bit easier to disentangle from indices, why should the inputs [5,7,4],[7,5,6] result in the output 7 instead of 5?

Comment: @BenGrossmann Yep, those would be the outputs since it compares the last element of the first list, with the all the elements from the second but in the same "semi-list", if no match, search again but now with the element immediately preceding the last from the first list, and look if that element appears in the second list, if it does, return it. I added that example on the post too.

Comment: @NachoGomez I think that makes sense. I've changed my answer to reflect what I think you're looking for

Comment: For `l1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` and `l2 = [5, 2, 6, 7, 8]` - should the answer be `5` or `2` and why? The accepted answer will say it's 5, but from the description in your question, 2 seems more appropriate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following can be made more efficient, but does work.

```
lists = [[1,2,3,4,5], # input to the script
         [5,4,3,2,1]]

sets = [set(), set()]
for a,b in zip(*lists):
    sets[0].add(a)
    sets[1].add(b)
    if sets[0]&sets[1]:
        print("first element in first overlap:")
        print(a)
        break
else:
    print("no overlap")
```

This results in the output

```
first element in first overlap:
3
```

Using `lists = [[5,7,6],[7,5,4]]` instead results in

```
first element in first overlap:
7
```

Comment: Note that the answer is 'no overlap' for `lists = [[4, 3, 2], [1, 2]]`, which clearly have an overlap.

Comment: @Grismar Interesting point. It's not clear what the desired behavior is in the case that the two lists have distinct lengths

Answer (score 3):

you can compare the elements of the two lists in the same loop:

```
l1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
l2 = [5,4,3,2,1]
 
for i, j in zip(l1, l2):
  if i == j:
    print('true')
  else:
    print('false')
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're really asking: What is (the index of) the first element that `l1` and `l2` have in common at the same index?

The solution:

```
next((i, a) for i, (a, b) in enumerate(zip(l1, l2)) if a == b)
```

How this works:

- `zip(l1, l2)` pairs up elements from `l1` and `l2`, generating tuples
- `enumerate()` gets those tuples, and keeps track of the index, i.e. `(0, (1, 5)`, `(1, (2, 4))`, etc.
- `for i, (a, b) in ..` generates those pairs of indices and value tuples
- The `if a == b` ensures that only those indices and values where the values match are yielded
- `next()` gets the next element from an iterable, you're interested in the first element that matches the condition, so that's what `next()` gets you here.

The working example:

```
l1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
l2 = [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]

i, v = next((i, a) for i, (a, b) in enumerate(zip(l1, l2)) if a == b)

print(f'index: {i}, value: {v}')  # prints "index: 2, value: 3"
```

If you're not interested in the index, but just in the first value they have in common:

```
l1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
l2 = [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]

v = next(a for a, b in zip(l1, l2) if a == b)

print(v)  # prints "3"
```

Edit: you commented and updated the question, and it's clear you don't want the first match at the same index between the lists, but rather the first common element in the heads of the lists.

(or, possibly the first element from the second list that is in the first list, which user @AndrejKesely provided an answer for - which you accepted, although it doesn't appear to answer the problem as described)

Here's a solution that gets the first match from the first part of each list, which seems to match what you describe as the problem:

```
l1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
l2 = [5, 2, 6, 7, 8]

v = next(next(iter(x)) for n in range(max(len(l1), len(l2))) if (x := set(l1[:n+1]) & set(l2[:n+1])))
print(v)  # prints "2"
```

Note: the solution fails if there is no match at all, with a `StopIteration`. Using short-circuiting with `any()` that can be avoided:

```
x = None if not any((x := set(l1[:n+1]) & set(l2[:n+1])) for n in range(max(len(l1), len(l2)))) else next(iter(x))
print(x)
```

This solution has `x == None` if there is no match, and otherwise `x` will be the first match in the shortest heads of both lists, so:

```
l1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
l2 = [5, 2, 6, 7, 8]  # result 2

l1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
l2 = [5, 6, 7, 8]  # result 5

l1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
l2 = [6, 7, 8]  # result None
```

Note that also:

```
l1 = [1, 2, 3]
l2 = [4, 3, 2]  # result 2, not 3
```

Both 2 and 3 seem to be valid answers here, it's not clear from your description why 3 should be favoured over 2?

If you do need that element of the two possible answers that comes first in `l2`, the solution would be a bit more complicated still, since the sets are unordered by definition, so changing the order of `l1` and `l2` in the answer won't matter.

If you care about that order, this works:

```
x = None if not any(x := ((set(l1[:n//2+1+n%2]) & set(l2[:n//2+1]))) for n in range(max(len(l1), len(l2)) * 2)) else next(iter(x))
```

This also works for lists with different lengths, unlike the more readable answer by user @BenGrossmann. Note that they have some efficiency in reusing the constructed sets and adding one element at a time, which also allows them to remember the last element added to the set corresponding with the first list, which is why they also correctly favor `3` over `2` in `[[1, 2, 3], [4, 3, 2]]`.

If the last answer is what you need, you should consider amending their answer (for example using [zip_longest](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest)) to deal correctly with lists of different lengths, since it will be more efficient for longer lists, and is certainly more readable.

Taking the solution from @BenGrossman, but generalising it for any number of lists, with any number of elements, and favouring the ordering you specified:

```
from itertools import zip_longest

lists = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
         [6, 7, 8, 5, 4]]

sets = [set() for _ in range(len(lists))]
for xs in zip_longest(*lists):
    for x, s in zip(xs, sets):
        s.add(x)
    if i := set.intersection(*sets):
        v = sorted([(lists[0].index(x), x) for x in i])[-1][1]
        break
else:
    v = None

print(v)
```

This works as described for all the examples, as well as for lists of unequal length, and will favour the elements that are farthest back in the first list (and thus earlier in the others).

Comment: This one is good! But when I trying with an example like l1 = [1,2,3,4,5] l2 = [3,4,5,6,7] it seems not to work :(, and the output should be 3. It says StopIteration.

Comment: Ah, perhaps you don't care about the first match in the same position then, just about the first element both lists have in common? I.e. for `l1 = [1,2,3,4,5] l2 = [3,4,5,6,7]` you expected an answer of `3` as well, and indices would be `(3, 1)`? That wasn't clear from the question, sorry.

Comment: I had a look at the accepted answer, but it doesn't look like that actually solves your problem  for `l1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` and `l2 = [5, 2, 6, 7, 8]`

Comment: You are correct in definition, probably it was not totally clear in the description (beginner's error since it is my first post), and it should have had more examples from the beginning, but the answer from Ben resolved the problem for that example too, it returns 2, which is the expected solution. I can see that what is not totally clear in the description is that the element from the first that we are comparing, is not checked with the entire second list, but only a part with the same element number that we used for the first, I hope it is clear with the examples added.

Comment: I think it is, but you should still consider what should happen if the lists are not of equal length.